# Chrome show hidden URL in the location bar

Tags: google-chrome

I need some help with my web browser, I use google chrome with version 36.0.1985.

In the most of times, when I open on google chrome I usually see the full URL in the location bar, but today I can see that the URL in the location bar are hiding. I have to click on the hidden url box to show the full URL. I have had a look in the settings, but I can't be able to find what settings I need to look at to untick the box to allow me to see the full URL in the location bar. It is annoyed me when google have changes things to make things more confused for people when they can't find what they are looking for and it is also annoyed me when they are hiding the url that I want to see the full URL what site I'm visiting.

It show like this:
[image]

Can you please tell me I can disable that annoyed small url box and how i can show the full URL in the location bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable this from Chrome's Experiments page - paste this in your Omnibox/location bar:

```
chrome://flags/#origin-chip-in-omnibox
```

Enable origin chip in the Omnibox should be set to disabled

[image]

Comment: @user3788310, was it set to Default before? (With Default, I don't get this behavior for https://google.co.uk—or any other domain.)

Comment: @Arjan with 'default'  it will function as disabled for some, enabled for others

Comment: 10 years later, not anymore :(